# How to solve Laravel sslcommerze integration error?

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I've done all the settings for demo payment gateway with sslcommerze, as per the below link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdGZLO0-76E
https://github.com/sslcommerz/SSLCommerz-Laravel

But I've an error after pressing Pay Now Button. "Error in Communication"
https://prnt.sc/tx321e

The Pop up appears but does not show select bank option. Hpw can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sandbox account from:
   [[https://developer.sslcommerz.com/registration/]]
   You can put any dummy data for registration, except your email address.
   [Note: Email address should be valid. You will receive a email verification code through your email. Put the information that you will remember].
2. Click here to login to the merchant panel:
   [[https://sandbox.sslcommerz.com/manage/]]
   Login ID: "That you have given during the registration"
   Password: "That you have given during the registration"
   [Note: Now you will get an email containing with STORE_ID and STORE_PASSWORD, it might take a couple of seconds]
3. Go to .env file from your laravel project:
   Add those following lines at the end of the file:
   STORE_ID = That you received from the mail
   STORE_PASSWORD = That you received from the mail
   Set your database name, username, and password at the same time.
4. Download the SslCommerz zip file or clone in any folder:
   [[https://github.com/sslcommerz/SSLCommerz-Laravel]]
   The file folder structure look like this,
   |-- config/
   |-- sslcommerz.php
   |-- app/Library/SslCommerz
   |-- AbstractSslCommerz.php (core file)
   |-- SslCommerzInterface.php (core file)
   |-- SslCommerzNotification.php (core file)
   |-- README.md
   |-- orders.sql (sample)
5. Now follow the steps to integrate payment gateway to integrate to your paypal project:
   Step 1: Extract the file
   Step 2: Copy the Library folder and put it in the laravel       project's app/ directory. If needed, then run composer dump -       o.
   Step 3: Copy the config/sslcommerz.php file into your laravel project's config/ folder.
   Step 4: Copy the SslCommerzPaymentController into your laravel project's Controllers folder
   Step 5: Copy the defined routes from routes/web.php into your laravel project's route file.
   Step 6: Add the below routes into the $excepts array of VerifyCsrfToken middleware.

   ```
   protected $except = [
                            '/pay-via-ajax', '/success','/cancel','/fail','/ipn'
                    ];
   ```

   Step 7: Copy all the view files under the resource folder and paste into your laravel project's resources/views/ folder.
   Step 8: To integrate popup checkout, use the below script before the end of body tag. Add it in any blade template that you want add your button.
   For Example: welcome.blade.php-> paste the code below, before ending of the body tag.

   For Sandbox:

   ```
            <script>
                 (function (window, document) {
                        var loader = function () {
                            var script = document.createElement("script"), tag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                        script.src = "https://sandbox.sslcommerz.com/embed.min.js?" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
                            tag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, tag);
                    };

                        window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load", loader, false) : window.attachEvent("onload", loader);
                    })(window, document);
            </script>
   ```

   For Live:

   ```
            <script>
                    (function (window, document) {
                        var loader = function () {
                        var script = document.createElement("script"), tag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                            script.src = "https://seamless-epay.sslcommerz.com/embed.min.js?" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
                            tag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, tag);
                    };

                        window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load", loader, false) : window.attachEvent("onload", loader);
                    })(window, document);
            </script>
    Step 9: Use the below button where you want to show the "Pay Now" button:
        Should be in the same place where step 8 was implemented.
   ```

   Pay Now
6. There is a orders.sql file in the SslCommerz folder. You can import it directrly from the phpmyadmin. Or you make a migration and model manually. And create new table according to the oraders.sql file columns.
7. You're done!

Some problem you might face.
Possible solution:-
-> Check DB class in the SslCommerzPaymentController and change, use DB into Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
-> Import SslCommerzPaymentController from the web.php.
-> Migrate the table.
-> Add this line of code to the payViaAjax method in the SslCommerzPaymentController, if you want to retrieve data dynamically from the form

```
    public function payViaAjax(Request $request, $id)
             {
                <<$requestData = (array)json_decode($request->cart_json);>>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy and put 4 key-value pairs to your `.env` file from below.

```
SSLCZ_STORE_ID=<your store id>
SSLCZ_STORE_PASSWORD=<your store password>
SSLCZ_TESTMODE=true
IS_LOCALHOST=true
```